# CouchDB cookie authentication is not working

Tags: authentication, couchdb

Fresh setup of CouchDB (2.1.1) on Debian seems to work in every aspect (CRUD of documents, adding new user, replication, etc), except the **proper** cookie authentication.

After setting `require_valid_user = true` in `chttpd` section, CouchDB started to require the authentication. The Basic Authentication works as expected:

```
curl -u foo:XXXX http://localhost:5984/_session
{"ok":true,"userCtx":{"name":"foo","roles":[]},"info":{"authentication_db":"_users","authentication_handlers":["cookie","default"],"authenticated":"default"}}
```

...but Cookie Authentication does not work:

```
curl http://localhost:5984/_session -H \
    'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'name=foo&password=XXXX'
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Authentication required."}
```

**BUT**

Setting `require_valid_user = false` in `chttpd` section makes the cookie authentication work:

```
curl http://localhost:5984/_session -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'name=foo&password=XXXX'
{"ok":true,"name":"foo","roles":[]}
```

(...where it makes authentication totally unnecessary at the same time, obviously.)

Relevant sections of current config which I expect it to work looks like this:

```
[chttpd]
authentication_db = _users
require_valid_user = true
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: `require_valid_user = true` should rarely be used in production, as all it does is require basic HTTP auth--it has nothing to do with cookie auth. And once authentication has been done via basic auth, there's no reason to re-authenticate with a cookie--so cookie auth is effectively turned off.

Comment: If `require_valid_user = true` should rarely be used, how can we prevent the database from unauthorized access in production?

Comment: With the `_security` endpoint as explained [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/intro/security.html?highlight=security#authorization).

Comment: Actually now it can be clearly understood that the crux of the original problem was arisen because of a forgotten `mydb/_security` file. If you point my false claim ("...where it makes authentication totally unnecessary at the same time, obviously." part) then your answer should be accepted as it solves the original problem.